# How to convert partial url string to full url link in php

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, url, partial

I have a text as description for example `"Hello, this is my website for getting access - http://www.abcxyz.com/testcontroller/testfunction"`

I need to show partial text as first 70 characters of description and followed by '...'.

So result for partial text should be `'Hello, this is my website for getting access - <a href='http://www.abcxyz.com/testcontroller/testfunction'>http://www.abcxyz.com/test...</a>'`. But the i need to convert the partial string to URL with full link.

I have used regular expression to convert string to url as -

```
function createUrlLink($text) {
        $url = '@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@';
        $return_text = preg_replace($url, '<a href="http$2://$4" target="_blank" title="$0">$0</a>', $text);
        return $return_text;
    }
```

This works fine for whole description. But i need to get this work for partial string url. Is there any solution ?

Comment: Do you have to accomplish your goal through regex? Why not use text-overflow: ellipsis for your element in css? I think it is easier and less risky that way. Unless your string is extremely long, which may increase the loadtime of the page, not sure though

Comment: @japanGuy This really a good solution for me. I'll first convert the url string to url link using regular expression and then apply this CSS. Will check the performance of loading but for now it will work. Thanks man!!!

Comment: oh, i just read your question again and realised that i misunderstood it :)

Comment: Can you mark this post as SOLVED or add a note at the top, please?